# How to concatenate and use a variable in a variable in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set 2 variables and have the firts variable within the second variable.

```
   var url = videoSpan.data("vimeoid");
   var thisVideo = '<span class"=video" data="url"></span>';
```

Comment: You could also do a replacement like `thisVideo = '<span class="video" data="__url__"></span>'.replace('__url__', url);`

Comment: FYI, `data` isn't valid attribute, use instead `data-*` attribute, e.g: `data-url`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var url = videoSpan.data("vimeoid");
var thisVideo = '<span class="video" data="' + url + '"></span>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `+` to concatenate variable/string/whatever.

```
var url = videoSpan.data("vimeoid");
var thisVideo = '<span class="video" data="' + url + '"></span>';
```